# How to change Live CD splash screen

Tags: themes, plymouth, live-cd

I'm remastering the ubuntu CD, I've changed some files in the isolinux folder (access.pcx, blank.pcx, gfxboot.cfg) and I have been able to change the first screen (background color to green):

[image]

But I can't change the second screen.

I made my own plymouth-theme package, and removed the plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text package. But this standard ubuntu screen is still displayed.

After installation, my own plymouth theme is well displayed.

So, I'm lost, is this screen related to plymouth? (if so, how can it be displayed after removing plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text) Or is it another file to modify?

Comment: Did you solved this problem already?

Answer (score 10):

I **found my [answer](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/backtrack-5-beginners-section/42516-change-bootsplash.html)** in backtrack linux forums. And since I set up the bounty I would like to explain a little bit what my problem was and how it got solved.

I was trying to [customize Ubuntu/KUbuntu 10.04 Live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) and I couldn't figure out how to change the splash screen that shows after isolinux.

Changing *playmouth* theme  available on the extracted **filesystem.squashfs** at `/lib/plymouth/themes/` **didn't do the trick**.

So I found [this message](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/backtrack-5-beginners-section/42516-change-bootsplash.html) stating that the **splash screen files used by the Live CD to boot reside in** `casper/initrd.lz`.

So, if you are interested to know how to extract and reconstruct this file, read the end of the [section 5.7.1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Live_CD_Kernel). Quote:

> To unpack the initrd.lz file, you need to do this:

```
cd extract-cd/casper
mkdir lztempdir
cd lztempdir
lzma -dc -S .lz ../initrd.lz | cpio -imvd --no-absolute-filenames
```

> And to re-create the initrd.lz file:

```
cp ../initrd.lz ../inird.lz.orig
find . | cpio --quiet --dereference -o -H newc | lzma -7 > ../initrd.lz
```

Comment: There is no initrd.lz file in Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: @RoshanGeorge - there is in 13.10...

Answer (score 1):

Did you rebuild the initramfs that the liveCD uses when booting the rest of the environment to include your new plymouth theme? I suspect that is the missing step.

Comment: yep, I'm using uck to remaster the CD, I execute "update-initramfs", and all my other changes (like the "splash.pcx" file that displays the first install menu) are taken into account...

Answer (score 0):

The second screenshot shows plymouth, but it is text-mode, not graphical.

You will have to make your own replacement for package plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text. The reason why text mode used is that the installer just plays safe, I guess.

This is also the plymouth that you get after installation when the installed machine has graphics drivers incapable of using kernel mode switching, so I would not suggest removing it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use this to trigger the right update functions when you change your plymouth theme

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Comment: This won't help change the Bootscreen on a LiveCD unless you somehow managed to chroot into an uncompressed LiveCD Initrd to run this command from...