# How do I create a boot disk from an existing installation?

Tags: live-cd, preferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

I want to make a boot CD that when used can run (without installing) an copy of Ubuntu already installed on my system with all the same preferences and programs as the version I am using at the moment.

I am running version 11.10 if it matters.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/83617/can-i-build-a-ubuntu-iso-from-a-manifest

Comment: you might look into live-builder: http://live.debian.net/

Comment: This question is not a duplicate as I'm asking for how to make a boot disk from an existing install, whereas the other one is for customising a plain ISO.

Answer (score 1):

I use Relinux quite often to build a live/installable iso from a preconfigured system, including settings and files in my home folder.  [Relinux Download page](https://launchpad.net/relinux)

A little guide to get you going [Relinux guide](http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/relinux-a-way-to-create-a-bootable-iso-out-of-your-system/)
To keep your settings you will need to run this from terminal `cd && sudo cp -r . /etc/skel/` before you make the iso.  Any problems, just ask.