# UBUNTU Desktop 15.04/15.10 with the SAME x86 window manager (identical) for ARM/ODROID XU4

Tags: 15.04, 15.10, arm

I have an ODROID XU2, it has enough power to run a Ubuntu Desktop that's normally available for x86 architecture, I do NOT want MATE, I want the Same as CD/ISO as the 15.04/15.10.

What's the process ? sources ? any "EASY" step by step document without requiring a Linux PHD ?

Comment: this is not so a trivial task but you can have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/83617/can-i-build-a-ubuntu-iso-from-a-manifest or https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd

Answer (score 0):

first i assume you are talking about DEs *(desktop environments)* and not window manager, since MATE is a full desktop environment and not a window manager.
*(to explain it a simple way: window manager are just responsible for the frames around your applications... like Compiz, Metacity, Marco, etc.)*

as you pointed out you need a ARM-build for a ARM-CPU, x86-build for a 32bit-CPU and so on...

---

usual a SBC *(single board conmputer)* has not enough "graphical power" to run a DE which needs 3D-acceleration like Unity *(the default ubuntu DE)* or GNOME 3.x.
for sure your ARM board may have enough power to run a ubuntu-system *(so there is the possibility to provide a MATE-built)*, but that don't have to mean also the default or every other packaged graphical desktop environment!

---

maybe i am wrong and you can try to install unity afterwards with the command `sudo apt-get install unity`, but i'm pretty sure that won't work and you will mess up your system.
**first backup your files and expect you have to reinstall ubuntu!!!** -- *don't blame me that i haven't warned you!*

Comment: i took a look at the web (but didn't found much about ODROID XU2) and it looks like it may have 3d-acceleration and be able to run the resource hungry `unity`... -- to avoid conflicts between different DEs i would flash an alternate-/server-version without a DE and then install `unity` or `ubuntu-desktop` (if you want the desktop with all other standard applications).