# How to customize ubuntu live cd plymouth theme?

Tags: 13.04, live-cd, plymouth

I am planning to customize Ubuntu 13.04 live cd. How is it possible to customize Ubuntu live cd plymouth theme in ubuntu 13.04 ?

Comment: start here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd/49679#49679

Comment: That doesn't answer how to customize the live cd plymouth theme. Some ehere I have read about editing initrd.lz file in the /casper directory, but, such a file is not present in that directory in Ubuntu 13.04 .

Comment: it does start the answer (but I did say: -start- here). You can trust me on that one :) The answer I made there is useable for 13.04 except we now work with dconf . You need to create a chroot environment with a downloaded ISO image load that ISO into the environment, alter it and then re-create the ISO. And no this is not something that is easy to do and requires thorough knowledge of the inner working of Ubuntu.

Comment: I think to edit the live cd plymouth we need to edit initrd file, but I couldnt find the same in ubuntu 13.04 iso.

Answer (score 0):

**There's an answer to the following question on here:**

[How to change Live CD splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10258/how-to-change-live-cd-splash-screen)

Though, editing this file only works on the next non-LTS (13.10)