# Splash screen before Ubiquity install

Tags: boot, 13.10, lubuntu, ubiquity

I am using the Ubuntu Customization Kit to build a customized linux distro. I am attempting to change the splash screen that appears before the Ubiquity Installer in Lubuntu 13.10.

I have been able to change the Plymouth splash screen that shows during boots and shutdowns/restarts. But not the one after the first screen that shows "Try Lubuntu without installing"/"Install Lubuntu" and before the Ubiquity Installer.

I have searched through forums for the last 3 weeks and have not been able to find a solution for this. Thank you in advance for any help in this.

[Video of splash screen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIEv60l3yqA&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: But don't you get THAT splash screen, then the separate plymouth theme? Do you want to change both?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have changed the plymouth theme but cant figure out how to change THAT splash screen.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question, but I was recently searching for this when trying to customize a 15.10 ISO.  I found no other answers to this, anywhere.  About 15 minutes ago (plus however long the re-mastering took so I could test this) I stumbled over the answer, so I'm going to provide it here in hopes that the reason for your trouble with 13.10 is the same reason for my troubles with 15.10.

Previously, I customized the boot splash for 14.10 by just editing the `splash.pcx` file.  That's not enough for 15.10.  You actually have to put a bunch of the files in the `isolinux` directory into a `cpio` archive named `bootlogo`.  Then, put that `bootlogo` file into the `isolinux` directory.

For example, if you happen to have `/tmp/isolinux` and it has the files from `/media/user/cdrom/isolinux`, and your modified pcx files, you could do the following:

```
cd /tmp/isolinux
cat bootlogo | cpio -t > /tmp/list
cpio -o < /tmp/list > bootlogo
```

Then you can go ahead and put the contents of `/tmp/isolinux` (or just the new `bootlogo`) wherever you need it.

A final note, if you want to modify the splash.pcx file, be sure to put it back into a 300x300 dpi format.  For example, using imagemagick: `mogrify -units PixelsPerInch -depth 300 splash.pcx`

Edit:  This appears to be the case for Ubuntu 16 as well.  That is, applying this method you can customize the Ubuntu 16 Live CD logo.

Answer (score 0):

For the splash screen,  you could try changing the `isolinux/splash.png` file in the `.iso` to the one you want - `splash.png` looks like:

[image: splash.png]

You may also need to change the `isolinux/splash.pcx` file as well.

Comment: I have changed both of those with no success :(

Comment: Weird init - the image needs to come from *somewhere*, it may be encoded inside a file or something. You have to edit the iso, save it, check whether it has saved, and burn it to a disk, and check whether it is on the disk as well.

Comment: It appears to be that the splash screen is sort of a modified grub - look inside `boot`... You may also want to check the settings in `isolinux/isolinux.cfg`, you may be able to to remove the logo or something.

Comment: It looks like it may be inside /remaster-iso/casper/initrd.lz. I followed the instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10258/how-to-change-live-cd-splash-screen . I found the image in initrd.lz, replaced it with my own, repacked initrd.lz, and packed my iso image. But the darn splash screen still shows up.

Comment: Removed the last line in isolinux/isolinux.cfg . Didn't work :/