# How to change isolinux folder of an ISO image?

Tags: boot, system-installation, xubuntu, logo, isolinux

I'm editing Xubuntu (xubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso) with Cubic (Custom Ubuntu ISO Creator). I need to change the logo image that appears in the menu when booting into BIOS mode when we press any key.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wlv2.jpg
I followed the information in the link below as a reference and managed to edit and package the bootlogo file that is in the isolinux folder, but I did it outside of Cubic using a system in Live mode to have normal access to the isolinux folder.
[How to change isolinux boot splash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816296/how-to-change-isolinux-boot-splash)
Is there any way I can do this inside Cubic and already leave my custom ISO with the isolinux folder and the bootlogo file I made previously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve my problem. I did the same questioningly on Cubic's official page and they detailed the step by step for me very easily.

> When you navigate to the Options page in Cubic, you will see three
> tabs at the top: Kernel, Preseed, and Boot.
>
> 1. Click on the Boot tab.
> 2. Then click on the "Show all files" toggle button at the top left of the header bar. (It is the 1st button to the right of the "<Back"
>    button).
> 3. This will expand all of the files in the "/boot/grub" and the "/isolinux" folders.
> 4. You can use the buttons in the header bar to copy files into these folders, create new files, or delete files. Note that the header bar
>    buttons change, depending on whether you've selected a file or a
>    directory in the tree view at the left. So, fore example, to create a
>    new file in a directory, you must select the directory first, in order
>    to activate the "Create a new file" header bar button.
> 5. You can view and edit text files by selecting them in the tree view on the left side. Your changes will automatically be saved when you
>    click the Next button. (By the way, files you add or update will
>    automatically be shown in the default list on this tab, so the next
>    time you launch your Cubic project, you won't need to click on the
>    "Show all files" toggle button.)

[Here is the link with more details.](https://answers.launchpad.net/cubic/+question/698864)

Comment: If there is something important on that link it needs to be in the answer. The link may not be there later when someone needs it.

Comment: I put the answer in full in the quote. Take a look at the link page, if you find something of more importance that deserves to be highlighted here I would be glad to add.